# How to install php yaml on CentOs?

Tags: php, centos, yaml

On the start I was getting this error:

```
Call to undefined function yaml_parse_file()
```

I have tried everything what I have found over google:

```
yum install libyaml
yum install yaml
yum install perl-yaml
```

and etc.

Now I'm getting:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/yaml.so' - /usr/lib64/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/yaml.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Exception: Extension yaml does not exist
```

Already added

```
extension=yaml.so
```

in php.ini file

Details:

```
CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
PHP 5.4.45
```

SS after I ran upper install commands:
[image]

What is the proper way to install yaml support in php?

Comment: Is there a php-yaml package? What version of CentOS?

Comment: Have you seen success messages after the yum commands?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - CentOS release 6.7 (Final)

Comment: @Klaus - added ss. Yes. every install was success.

Comment: You're using PHP, not Perl. There's no need to install `perl-YAML`. Also, installing the right PHP extension will install all required dependencies, so don't worry about `yaml` or `libyaml`. Show the results where you successfully install `php-yaml` from EPEL.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - http://screencast.com/t/WqkiFg34

Comment: You need "php-pecl-yaml" If using "php" from base repo, you can find it in EPEL. If using another PHP stack (I see webtatic in your repo) you need to ask you provider, or choose a better provider.

Comment: I mean: You need "php-pecl-yaml" If using "php" from base repo, you can find it in EPEL. If using another PHP stack (Which is obviously not the case, as I see webtatic in your enabled repos, and you say 5.4.45) you need to ask you provider, or choose a better provider.

Answer (score 1):

php-yaml from epel repository:

```
php-pecl-yaml-1.1.1-5.el6.x86_64 : Support for YAML 1.1 serialization
using the LibYAML library 
Repo : epel 
Matched from: 
Other: php-yaml
```

For repo: **sudo yum install epel-release**

For package: **sudo yum install php-yaml**

And remember to restart httpd

Comment: yum install php-yaml? What was I ment, yum install epel-release is the repo only.

Comment: installed epel-release and after that i ran: yum --enablerepo=epel install php-yaml but I'm still getting error.